# What does "through model" mean in loopback?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

When defining relation using "slc loopback:relation", it prompts about "through model" at the last line.

```
? Select the model to create the relationship from: CoffeeShop
? Relation type: has many
? Choose a model to create a relationship with: Reviewer
? Enter the property name for the relation: reviewers
? Optionally enter a custom foreign key:
? Require a through model? No
```

Could someone briefly explain what a through model is?
Some example will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17):

Through model is generally used for `many to many` data relation. 
For example you have 3 models:

1. `User` with `id` and `username` fields;
2. `Team` with `id` and `teamName` fields;
3. `TeamMember` with `userId` and `teamId` fields.

`User` can be a member of many `Team` and `Team` can have many `User`. And the relation of `User` and `Team` will be stored in `TeamMember`.

To create `many to many` relations in loopback you have to add `relation` property to your model definition files:

1. In `User` model definition file (user.json)

```js
"relations": {
  "teams": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "team",
    "foreignKey": "userId",
    "through": "teamMember"
  }
}
```

2. In `Team` model definition file

```js
"relations": {
  "users": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "user",
    "foreignKey": "teamId",
    "through": "teamMember"
  }
}
```

3. And in `TeamMember` model definition file

```js
"relations": {
  "user": {
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "model": "user",
    "foreignKey": "userId"
  },
  "team": {
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "model": "team",
    "foreignKey": "teamId"
  }
}
```

You can also find information about "through model" on StrongLoop's [docs](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasManyThrough+relations)

Comment: any idea how to add data in TeamMember model, through loopback explorer?

Comment: Explanation on Loopback documentation: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/HasManyThrough-relations.html